# PostSharp access to local variables

Tags: vb.net, postsharp

Recently I have been evaluating the uses of PostSharp in respect of Error Reporting. Having found out that .Net doesn't provide any particularly easy mechanism of obtaining values within the Stack Frame (such as parameters), I have been looking into using Postsharp for Method Injection Techniques.

This proves very useful in obtaining the values of the parameters of the methods using OnEnter, however I will still need to cache this in some form.

However, when it comes to accessing local variables, because they are on the stack, I'm not quite sure if/how this could be achieved using postsharp or another alternate library. I have already looked into the Unmanaged API's for both Profiling and Debugging and this seems like a rather heavy handed approach for something as simple as generating an error report.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with PostSharp and I guess it is very difficult to achieve with any IL weaving tool.

You would need to use low level IL rewriting tools like [Cecil](https://github.com/jbevain/cecil).

[Generating a minidump file](https://tripleemcoder.com/2012/01/08/creating-minidumps-with-postsharp-aspects/) when an exception is thrown would be an remarkable option as well.

Comment: I suspected as much, but I thought I'd ask the question anyways. Basically what we are trying to achieve is an emulation of another tool we used to use, but do to lack of updating and support we've had to scrap, which provides as part of the stack trace locals and parameter values. Also I'm a bit rusty when it comes to the generating and reading of a minidump file (I've already had the pain of learning how to read PDB file).